# python - pandas with openpyxl damages my workbook

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

Using pandas with the openpyxl engine I want to open an excel woorkbook and add a sheet.

Because, the sheets are growing and getting quit big I want to create a new sheet without reading all the other sheet.

So instead of xlsxwriter, I did start using openpyxl, however I get the following issue that the file gets damaged and needs to recovered by excel.

After that, when I run it a second time, I get the python error that the excel file is 'raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")'.

This my test code:

```
 import openpyxl
 import pandas

 from pandas import ExcelWriter
 from pandas import ExcelFile
 from openpyxl import Workbook
 from openpyxl import load_workbook

 sheet1 = 'sheet1'
 sheet2 = 'sheet2'

 if os.path.exists(filename):
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename) 
 else:
    workbook = Workbook()

 writer = pandas.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl')

 writer.book = workbook
 df_1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet1)

 writer.save()
 writer.close()

 time.sleep(2) # to give it some time. But doesn't help :(

 if os.path.exists(filename):
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename) 
 else:
    workbook = Workbook()

 writer = pandas.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl')

 writer.book = workbook
 df_2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet2)
 writer.save()
 writer.close()
```

Any suggestions how to solve this? Or do I miss something?

btw, excel 365 - 16.46 macOS